# Producer Exception Handler in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am facing a scenario in my Kafka Stream job written in Spring Cloud Stream where producer failed with an exception.

Checked in kafka stream, there is a config to handle the same by:
`default.production.exception.handler`

Unable to find subsequent handler in spring cloud stream.
Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Spring boot version: `2.2.4.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

> `default.production.exception.handler`

You can set any arbitrary Kafka Streams property using the

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration
```

property.

See [the documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_kafka_streams_binder_properties).

So just add it there.